# Get words from a string using dart

Tags: string, dart

I am working with dart and I need to get all the words in a string

```
final String words = 'My name is futter'
```

I want to be able to store each word in a variable

```
final string Word1;
final string Word2;
final string Word3;
final string Word4;
```

Comment: OK, and did you try anything before posting? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: That can only work if you know a limit on the number of words before you write the program. Are you sure you don't just want a list of the words? (And then you'll have to specify what you consider a word)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split a `String` into a `List<String>` using `split(String pattern)` :

```
final String string = 'My name is futter';
var words = string.split(" ");
words.forEach(print);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I had already solved it, thank you for being part of this learning.